# Why does C# and Java compile JustInTime instead of compling everything once first run/installed?

Tags: java, c#

Seemingly you can compile the bytecode into native during some installation of application, without loosing the cross-platform-issue.

Installation doesn't necessarily means a GUI installation. That can optionally be just a silence process that happens on the first running of the executable. (With or without a graphical process bar)

That would be (I think) much easier for the developers of the languages, and result in a faster executable, without loosing the adaptations to the current machine.

Comment: Read this QA: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2106380/what-are-the-advantages-of-just-in-time-compilation-versus-ahead-of-time-compila

Comment: Well, this is a very interesting subject indeed, but I don't think that it's a good question for StackOverflow... Not in this form.

Answer (score 1):

Something similar *does* happen behind the scenes (at least with .NET). [NGen](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6t9t5wcf%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) *can* cache native images in the *native image cache*, so that your code won't have to be compiled a second time on that machine.

> Ngen.exe creates native images, which are files containing compiled processor-specific machine code, and installs them into the native image cache on the local computer. The runtime can use native images from the cache instead of using the just-in-time (JIT) compiler to compile the original assembly.

Comment: I'm not asking HOW to do that. I'm asking why that was the choice of the designers in the first place, while it seems much more difficult

Comment: You asked "Why does C# and Java compile JustInTime instead of compling everything once first run/installed?", and my answer is "The question is moot, because the code *is* compiled once, when you run it for the first time".

Comment: I'm quite sure the JIT is still doing work even in the second run.

Answer (score -1):

JIT compilation makes the code much faster while running than using an interpreter, but the initial cost can be prohibitive, depending on what is being done.